# Elastic Beanstalk, configuration never ran?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am working on deploying the app throught elastic beanstalk.

However, I have noticed that the config files are never ran, I know this by:

I have set a document root, when I go to settings throught AWS it is empty,
I have set a environment variables which are also empty, however when it set it manually throught the website they are working fine, in event log (while deploying) I apparently should see output saying that config has ran successfully. I tried every log and it wasn't mentioned anywhere.

I am running Laravel 5.4 and .ebextensions folder is created in root of the project. Inside it I have 01-environment.config:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini:
    document_root: /public
    memory_limit: 512M
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:sqsd:
    HttpPath: /worker/queue
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    APP_ENV: production
    APP_KEY: base64:MDKarorDueozTysvq50zDJET7es7MsVoTe3r001+xBs=
    APP_DEBUG: true
```

02-deploy.config

```
   container_commands:
      01-migrations:
        command: "php artisan migrate --force"
        command: "php artisan key:generate"
        command: "php artisan config:clear"
        command: "php artisan config:cache"

    files:
      "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_make_storage_writable.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
          #!/usr/bin/env bash
          echo "Making /storage writeable..."
          chmod -R 777 /var/app/current/storage
          chmod -R 777 /var/app/current/bootstrap/cache
          if [ ! -f /var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log ]; then
              echo "Creating /storage/logs/laravel.log..."
   owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      echo "Making /storage writeable..."
      chmod -R 777 /var/app/current/storage
      chmod -R 777 /var/app/current/bootstrap/cache
      if [ ! -f /var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log ]; then
          echo "Creating /storage/logs/laravel.log..."
          touch /var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log
          chown webapp:webapp /var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log
      fi

      if [ ! -d /var/app/current/public/storage ]; then
          echo "Creating /public/storage symlink..."
          ln -s /var/app/current/storage/app/public /var/app/current/public/sto$
      fi

  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/publishlogs.d/laravel-logs.conf":
      chown webapp:webapp /var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log
      fi

      if [ ! -d /var/app/current/public/storage ]; then
          echo "Creating /public/storage symlink..."
          ln -s /var/app/current/storage/app/public /var/app/current/public/sto$
      fi

  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/publishlogs.d/laravel-logs.conf":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      /var/app/current/storage/logs/*.log

  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/https_redirect.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
  content: |
      /var/app/current/storage/logs/*.log

  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/https_redirect.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
      RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=307,L]
```

As you see I have redirect here also, which doesn't work as it always go on http by default, I don't get laravel log on S3 either or any other command. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

`/var/log/eb-activity.log` should show your `.config` files being executed.

In your `02-deploy.config`, there are several issues.

- Under `container_commands`, you can only have one command per `command:`. Try something like this:

  ```
  container_commands:
    01-migrations:
      command: "php artisan migrate --force"
    02-generate-key:
      command: "php artisan key:generate"
    03-config-clear:
      command: "php artisan config:clear"
    04-config-cache:
      command: "php artisan config:cache"
  ```
- You have inconsistent whitespace. YAML files are very sensitive to whitespace, so make sure that you're using the same amount of indent (usually two spaces) per level.
- Might just be a copy/paste problem, but the `99_make_storage_writable.sh` section has some duplicated lines.